# convert mol/m2 to μg/m3

Tags: geochemistry, air-pollution, environmental-protection, biogeochemistry, environmental-sensors

Sentinel-5P satellite provides high-resolution data products on concentration levels for several atmospheric trace gases (NO<sub>2</sub>, SO<sub>2</sub>, O<sub>3</sub>, and others), which are measured in mol/m<sup>2</sup> within the total or tropospheric column.
I want to convert mol/m<sup>2</sup> to μg/m<sup>3</sup>. How can I do this?

Comment: This question has already been asked, and answered, [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19391/10735) and the answer is pretty much sorry you can't do that directly.

Comment: There's actually another duplicate which has an answer as well, here:  https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/how-do-i-convert-sentinel-5p-tropomi-vertical-column-density-to-concentration?rq=1